# For how long does one test positive for COVID-19 after being infected with COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, test

I read on https://www.thehealthy.com/infectious-disease/how-long-can-you-test-positive-for-covid/  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210809003920/https://www.thehealthy.com/infectious-disease/how-long-can-you-test-positive-for-covid/)):

> According to the CDC, you can **test positive up to three months after exposure** even though you probably won’t be contagious for that long. But these parameters may vary among vaccinated individuals.

However, I would like to have a better idea of the distribution of for how many one tests positive for COVID-19 after being infected with COVID-19. (E.g., x % of individuals infected with COVID-19 took y days to test negative).

---

What I have found so far:

- I did search on Google for quite some time but the seemingly rather easy information is surprisingly difficult to find.
- I am aware that individuals may test even positive clinical recovery and previous negative results. From {1}:

  > Similar to that reported elsewhere {2}, 18% of patients with COVID-19 in our institution became RT-PCR positive for SARS-CoV-2 RNA after clinical recovery and previous negative results

---

References:

- {1} Liotti  FM, Menchinelli  G, Marchetti  S,  et al.  Positive SARS-CoV-2 RNA test results among patients who recovered from COVID-19 with prior negative results.  * JAMA Intern Med*. Published online November 12, 2020. doi:[10.1001/jamainternmed.2020.7570](http://jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?doi=10.1001/jamainternmed.2020.7570)
  [Article](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2773053)[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Positive%20SARS-CoV-2%20RNA%20test%20results%20among%20patients%20who%20recovered%20from%20COVID-19%20with%20prior%20negative%20results.&author=FM%20Liotti&author=G%20Menchinelli&author=S%20Marchetti&publication_year=&journal=JAMA%20Intern%20Med&volume=&pages=)
- {2} Kang  H, Wang  Y, Tong  Z, Liu  X.  Retest positive for SARS-CoV-2 RNA of “recovered” patients with COVID-19: Persistence, sampling issues, or re-infection?  * J Med Virol*. 2020;1-3. doi:[10.1002/jmv.26114](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jmv.26114)[PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/32492212)[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Retest%20positive%20for%20SARS-CoV-2%20RNA%20of%20%E2%80%9Crecovered%E2%80%9D%20patients%20with%20COVID-19%3A%20Persistence%2C%20sampling%20issues%2C%20or%20re-infection%3F&author=H%20Kang&author=Y%20Wang&author=Z%20Tong&author=X%20Liu&publication_year=2020&journal=J%20Med%20Virol&volume=&pages=1-3)

Comment: "[how long] after being *contaminated*" is a somewhat irrelevant and hard to determine point for most patients. So I doubt you'll find good stats for this.

Comment: @Fizz can be estimated eg via contact tracing or time it takes to present symptoms. If easier we can directly count days after showing symptoms (which would reduce the statistics to the symptomatic patients).

Comment: "Contaminated" is simply the wrong word and means something entirely different. One might never test positive after coming in contact with the virus, so we have no way of measuring "contamination" or even detecting that it has happened. Just plain wrong word.

Comment: @CareyGregory which word would you use?

Comment: I would use "infection." It's the only measurable variable.

Comment: Re: "I would like to have a better idea of the distribution of for how many one tests positive for COVID-19 after being contaminated with COVID-19. " It almost certainly depends on the vaccination history of the person, the infection history of the person, the COVID variant(s) involved, the specific COVID test(s) involved, and so forth. Thus, it's unlikely such "seemingly rather easy information" is available. Do you have a particular scenario in mind?

Comment: @Armand 1 shot of Janssen vaccine a few weeks ago, no prior infection before the vaccination, 30 yo male, no immunity disorder, delta variant. But then if I add that in the question it may get closed as personal medical advice :/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Certainly fewer studies have been done with Janssen than with Moderna/Pfizer, mostly for non-scientific reasons. I tend to think of Astra Zeneca as a rough equivalent, and suspect that qualitative findings with AZ would carry over to Janssen. E.g. two doses give much better protection than one, performance against delta, and so forth. I remember seeing a number of reports from the UK health authorities.

Comment: @CareyGregory Good point, thanks! I edited the question.